# How to change DocuSign registered email address

Tags: docusignapi

How to change DocuSign registered email address
I press My Profile->Email Address->UPDATE

When I enter the New Email, it needs to be verified. After I fill in the verification code, I still can't change it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug of some sort. Not sure trying again would work , but I would try a few more times just in case, maybe do this in  new incognito browser etc.
In any event, you may need to contact customer support.
I would also say if you're a developer (this is a developer forum after all) and this is for your developer account, why not just create a new one with that other email address? that's much easier, you can have a new developer account, 100% free, no issues by just going to https://go.docusign.com/o/sandbox/?postActivateUrl=https://developers.docusign.com/

Comment: Thank you,  This is not a developer account, but my main account for payment.